# two queries merging (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have two queries but i dont know hot to merge them. i am trying to achieve to insert the latest price into the list...

first one is :

```
SELECT     
     ITM.CODE
    ,itm.NAME
    ,min(isnull(price,0)) [min price] 
    ,max(isnull(price,0)) [max]
    ,SUM(total)/SUM(amount) as [avr] 
FROM LG_092_ITEMS ITM 
INNER JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE STL 
    ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
WHERE PRICE > 0 
    AND TRCODE = 1 
    AND CANCELLED = 0 
    AND INVOICEREF > 0
GROUP BY ITM.name , itm.code
ORDER BY code
```

the second one is :

```
SELECT
    ITM.CODE, itm.NAME, max (stl.date_) [latest date] , price as [latest price]

FROM LG_092_ITEMS ITM 
INNER JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE STL 
    ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
WHERE PRICE > 0 
    AND TRCODE = 1 
    AND CANCELLED = 0 
    AND INVOICEREF > 0 


    group by code, name, stl.DATE_ , price
```

Comment: Does the second query work  ?

Comment: Could you provide the structure of your tables and some sample data please?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnyfkbrJQyhJnjYka-reiIXwSwzx

Comment: @UmutK:please check on how to ask and get help faster  :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Dear @TheGameiswar,

you'r correct, the query should be as

.

SELECT
    ITM1.CODE, itm1.NAME, max (stl.date_) [latest date] , price as [latest price]
    
FROM LG_092_ITEMS ITM1 
INNER JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE STL 
    ON ITM1.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
WHERE PRICE > 0 
    AND TRCODE = 1 
    AND CANCELLED = 0 
    AND INVOICEREF > 0 
    
    
    group by code, name, stl.DATE_ , price

Comment: @UmutK:please update question

Comment: @TheGameiswar already updated... thanks for the assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but i think it will work :)

```
with CTE AS (
    SELECT ITM.CODE
        ,itm.NAME
        ,STL.price AS [latestprice]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITM.CODE, itm.NAME ORDER BY stl.date_ desc) AS RowN
    FROM LG_092_ITEMS AS ITM
    JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE AS STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
    WHERE STL.price > 0
        AND TRCODE = 1
        AND CANCELLED = 0
        AND INVOICEREF > 0
)
SELECT ITM.CODE
    ,itm.NAME
    ,min(isnull(STL.price, 0)) [min price]
    ,max(isnull(STL.price, 0)) [max]
    ,SUM(total) / SUM(amount) AS [avr]
    ,max(CTE.latestprice) AS latestprice
FROM LG_092_ITEMS AS ITM
JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE AS STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
JOIN CTE ON CTE.CODE = itm.code AND CTE.name = ITM.name AND CTE.RowN = 1
WHERE STL.price > 0
    AND TRCODE = 1
    AND CANCELLED = 0
    AND INVOICEREF > 0
GROUP BY ITM.NAME,itm.code
ORDER BY itm.code
```

For more info on CTE see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: thanks for your time but not working ...

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'LG_092_01_STLINE.PRICE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: any other suggestions ? @m-grue

Comment: Just a small group by that was not needed :)

Comment: works like a charm ! thanks a lot ! 

another issue i have is, i cannot use query starting "with" together with "union all" 

any suggestion ?

Comment: Just move "WITH CTE AS (...)" to the top, and it should work.

Comment: but i want the whole code working for LG_092_ITEMS , LG_093_ITEMS, LG_094_ITEMS etc...

Comment: you can have mutiple CTE in the start of the script. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: Multiple CTE query definitions can be defined in a nonrecursive CTE. The definitions must be combined by one of these set operators: UNION ALL, UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT.

Comment: but the reality is different than explained...  

[Reality](http://i.imgur.com/IyC1vsb.jpg)

Comment: i also removed the first **order by** before the **union all** but the result didnt change    

_Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon._  

i even used **;** , no help...

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you're looking for is `JOIN`

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/

Comment: this can be a comment and op is looking for SQLServer

Comment: Thanks for the language tip. Wrote answer when language wasn't specified, but should have written that the Oracle link is just an example reference. I wanted to comment first, but then I thought "use join" is the answer to "how to merge?" so I posted my answer as an answer. Is this behaviour discouraged?

Comment: Answers are typically for full answers to the question that will resolve the OP's issue. Comments are for links to helpful information and further questions. I think it's fairly clear in this instance that the OP knows how to join based upon the sample queries provided,

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * 
 from 
 (
 SELECT     
     ITM.CODE
    ,itm.NAME
    ,isnull(price,0) as [latest price]
    ,min(isnull(price,0))   over (partition by ITM.name, itm.code) as [min price] 
    ,max(isnull(price,0))   over (partition by ITM.name, itm.code) as [max]
    ,SUM(total)/SUM(amount) over (partition by ITM.name, itm.code) as [avr]   
    ,row_number()           over (partition by ITM.name, itm.code order by stl.date_ desc) as rn
FROM LG_092_ITEMS ITM 
INNER JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE STL 
    ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
WHERE PRICE > 0 
    AND TRCODE = 1 
    AND CANCELLED = 0 
    AND INVOICEREF > 0    
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
ORDER BY code
```

with price > 0 you don't need the isnull

Comment: thanks for the time and effort but error :


Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: still something is missing... 

'Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'LG_092_ITEMS.CODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: i've tried the updated one (the one w/o the group by) of course and wrote the new error message...

Comment: I cannot image how you would get that message.  Why would SQL put out that message if there was no  GROUP BY clause?   Sorry I could not be of help.

Answer (score 0):

We found another way around with a help of my friend... Hope it will help to someone else as well...

```
SELECT ITM.CODE
    ,itm.NAME
    ,min(isnull(STL.price, 0)) [min price]
    ,max(isnull(STL.price, 0)) [max]
    ,SUM(total) / SUM(amount) AS [avr]
    --SON SATINALMA FIYATI
    ,ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 PRC.PRICE FROM LG_092_01_STLINE AS PRC
    WHERE PRC.STOCKREF = ITM.LOGICALREF
        AND PRC.PRICE > 0
        AND PRC.TRCODE = 1
        AND PRC.CANCELLED = 0
        AND PRC.INVOICEREF > 0
    ORDER BY PRC.DATE_ DESC), 0) AS latestprice  
FROM LG_092_ITEMS AS ITM
INNER JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE AS STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
WHERE STL.PRICE > 0
    AND TRCODE = 1
    AND CANCELLED = 0
    AND INVOICEREF > 0
GROUP BY ITM.LOGICALREF, ITM.CODE, ITM.NAME
ORDER BY ITM.CODE
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    SELECT     ITM.CODE, itm.NAME, min(isnull(price,0)) [min price] , max(isnull(price,0)) [max], SUM(total)/SUM(amount) as [avr] , 
    FROM         LG_092_ITEMS ITM inner join
    LG_092_01_STLINE STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
    WHERE     PRICE > 0 AND TRCODE = 1 AND CANCELLED = 0 AND INVOICEREF > 0
    GROUP BY ITM.name , itm.code
    order by code
    UNION
    SELECT     price as [latest price]
    FROM         LG_092_ITEMS ITM inner join
    LG_092_01_STLINE STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
    WHERE     PRICE > 0 AND TRCODE = 1 AND CANCELLED = 0 AND INVOICEREF > 0 and (date_ = max(date_)
    GROUP BY ITM.name , itm.code
    order by code
```

The UNION clause will merge both queries keeping only unique values.

Comment: Union with a different amount of columns in the select?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.